# how can change foreach array to getting a item in php 7.4 (I didn't have problem in php 5.4)

Tags: php, foreach

I didn't have problem with this function in php 5.4 but in upgrading script i have this probem. my function in the function.php file through which I call the language files of the project.

```
class sblib {
    var $sblang = "";
    var $lang = "";

    function load_lang($file_lang) {
        global $sbportals;
        $mlang = $this->sblang;
        if ($sbportals->member['sb_lang']) {    
            $dir = @opendir($this->sitepath."sbportal/lang/");
            while (($dirt = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
                $sbl = strtolower (substr($dirt, 0, 3));        
                $bol = strtolower (substr($sbportals->member['sb_lang'], 0, 3));
                if ($sbl == $bol && $dirt != ".htaccess" && $dirt != "htaccess" && $dirt != "index.html" && $dirt != "English_Reference") {
                    $mlang = $this->sitepath."sbportal/lang/".$dirt;
                }   
            }   
            closedir($dir);
        }

        require "$mlang/$file_lang";
        foreach ($langsb as $k => $v) {

            $this->lang[$k] = stripslashes($v);////this line///

            }
    }

    $sblib = new sblib;
    $sblib->stimer();
    $sblib->sblang = $sb_PATH."sbportal/lang/".$sb_LANG;
```

This is the content of the language file (lang_search.php):

```
$langsb['ad_langs_group'] = "Group";
$langsb['ad_langs_group_title'] = "Group Title";
$langsb['ad_langs_sel_title'] = "Language Administration";
$langsb['ad_langs_sel_info'] = "Choose the language";
```

Then by calling the function (once in each file of the project) as follows

```
$sblib->load_lang("lang_search.php");
```

And using the calling function wherever I need as below

```
{$sblib->lang['download']}
```

I can use translation files for translate of each words. I had no problem until php 5.6, but I see this error when upgrading to 7.4.

```
Warning: Illegal.string.offset.'download'.in ... (////this line///)
```

please help me to solve.

I have checked all the ways and pages of the stackoverflow.

Comment: Do `var_dump($sblib->lang);` and see what it contains. Evidently it doesn't contain what your code is expecting it to. If you're not familiar with basic [debugging](https://www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/) now would be a good time to learn

Comment: P.S. Since `$langsb` doesn't contain any value called "download", it's unclear why you expect the resulting `lang` object to, either? What was the logic there?

Comment: P.P.S. `I didn't have problem with this function in php 5.4`...It would have always had a problem, and not been able to read the nonexistent value, it's just that it would likely have not have generated a similar error if it wasn't enabled, or reporting was less strict. But the actual bug would have been the same, just less visible.